# Sum one dataframe based on value of other dataframe in same index/row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sum values of a dataframe conditionally, based on the values of a different dataframe. Say for example I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,-1,5],[2,1,1],[3,0,0]],index=[0,1,2],columns = [0,1,2])

index   0   1   2        
-----------------
0       1   -1   5    
1       2   1   1  
2       3   0   0
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,1,3],[1,1,2],[0,2,1]],index=[0,1,2],columns = [0,1,2])

index   0   1   2    
-----------------
0       1   1   3   
1       1   1   2  
2       0   2   1
```

Now what I would like is that for example, if the row/index value of df1 equals 1, to sum the location of those values in df2.

In this example, if the condition is 1, then the sum of df2 would be 4. If the condition was 0, the result would be 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df2.where(df1.eq(1)).to_numpy().sum()
# or
# df2.where(df1.eq(1)).sum().sum()
```

output: `4.0`

intermediate:

```
df2.where(df1.eq(1))
     0    1    2
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option with Pandas' [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df2.query("@df1==1").sum().sum()
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one wants to store the value in the variable `value`, there are various options to achieve that. Will leave below two of them.

---

**Option 1**

One can simply do the following

```
value = df2[df1 == 1].sum().sum()

[Out]: 4.0 # numpy.float64

# or

value = sum(df2[df1 == 1].sum())

[Out]: 4.0 # float
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
value = df2.where(df1 == 1, 0).sum().sum()

[Out]: 4.0 # numpy.int64

# or

value = sum(df2.where(df1 == 1, 0).sum())

[Out]: 4 # int
```

---

**Notes:**

- Both `df2[df1 == 1]` and `df2.where(df1 == 1, 0)` give the following output

  ```
       0    1    2
   0  1.0  NaN  NaN
   1  NaN  1.0  2.0
   2  NaN  NaN  NaN
  ```
- Depending on the desired output (`float`, `int`, `numpy.float64`,...) one method might be better than the other.